# Are different atomic operations(e.g. __sync_fetch_and_add and __sync_lock_test_and_set) mutually exclusive？

Tags: c, multithreading, gcc, atomic, mutual-exclusion

I am learning atomic operations supported by hardware. I know there are many atomic operations, for example, compare and swap(CAS)、fetch and add(FAA)、test and set.

I understand that when we use just one atomic operation at a shared resource on a multi-threaded program, different threads can access the shared resource mutually exclusively. such as the following example:

```c
    // this code implements a spinlock with CAS
    void lock_init(int *lock){
        *lock = 0;
    }

    void lock(int *lock) {
        while(__sync_val_compare_and_swap(lock, 0, 1) != 0) {
            ; // busy-looping
        }
    }

    void unlock(int *lock) {
        *lock = 0;
    }
```

On the code above, all threads that access the lock variable will use CAS atomic operation to operate the lock variable mutually exclusively.

However, when we use multiple different atomic operations on the same variable, can these different atomic operations access the shared variable mutually exclusively?

Take the following code as an example：

```c
template<typename T> 
class AtomicIntegerT
{
    public:
        AtomicIntegerT()
            : value_(0) 
        {
        }
    
        T get() {
            return __sync_val_compare_and_swap(&value_, 0, 0);
        }   

        T getAndAdd(T x) {
            return __sync_fetch_and_add(&value_, x);
        }

        T addAndGet(T x) {
            return getAndAdd(x) + x;
        }

        T getAndSet(T newValue) {
            return __sync_lock_test_and_set(&value_, newValue);
        }

    private:
        volatile T value_; 
};
```

I want to implement atomic variables with __sync_val_compare_and_swap、__sync_fetch_and_add、__sync_lock_test_and_set. using __sync_val_compare_and_swap to get value of variable; using __sync_fetch_and_add to add some value on variable; using __sync_lock_test_and_set to implement atomic assignment operations.

when one thread is executing getAndSet(）while another thread is executing getAndAdd(), can those two threads access value_ mutually exclusively?

The more general problem is that are different atomic operations(e.g. __sync_fetch_and_add and __sync_lock_test_and_set) mutually exclusive？

Comment: Wait a minute, this is a [c] question, but your code is using `template<>`?   Since you're actually using C++, even more reason to just use `std::atomic<T>` instead of rolling your own.  That template class does exactly what yours does.  (Not that there's anything wrong with C11 `_Atomic` or `atomic_int`, but C++ overloads make it easier to use `std::memory_order` args.  And if you want to sometimes access a value atomically and sometimes not, C++20 has `std::atomic_ref`.)

Comment: Anyway, C++ `std::atomic` will also make sure your `value_` is properly aligned to be atomic, not just to be a plain `int64_t` for example.  And yes, that can matter, like for `int64_t` on some 32-bit ISAs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the deprecated GNU C `__sync` builtins and the [modern GNU C `__atomic` builtins](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/_005f_005fatomic-Builtins.html) are all atomic operations on the object.  You can use two different atomic operations from different threads and get consistent results.

Multiple threads can `__atomic_load_n`  in parallel, no mutual exclusion needed between pure loads.  Your `get` would be much more efficient with that instead of `__sync` CAS with `0,0`!

But otherwise yes, `__sync` and `__atomic` builtins are equivalent mutual exclusion as far as operations on that object.  The deprecated legacy `__sync` builtins are also equivalent to a full barrier as part of the operation (like `atomic_thread_fence(memory_order_seq_cst)`, not just a seq_cst *operation*), so they potentially create synchronization like mutual exclusion.

`__atomic` operations on different objects with orders weaker than `__ATOMIC_SEQ_CST` can appear to be overlapping, but each operation is still atomic.

The `__atomic` builtins are what `<atomic>` uses to implement `std::atomic<T>` uses in C++.  In C `<stdatomic.h>` and `_Atomic` are the portable way to use the same functionality as the `__atomic` builtins.  (Except ISO C doesn't have a way to do non-atomic access to an object in some parts of your program, and atomic access only during multi-threaded parts.  C++20 `std::atomic_ref<>` does that, or you can roll your own in GNU C with `__atomic` builtins.)